# Interpreting the 'eruptions' variable option for knitr chunk in RMarkdown

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I have the following knitr chunk obtained from RStudio base Rmarkdown-Shiny runtime template:

````
```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),

  sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
)

renderPlot({
  hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
       xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```
````

What is the use of `eruptions` option in `{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}`

Answer (score 1):

It is the name of the chunk.

You cannot give same name to different chunks.

Comment: What's the purpose of naming the chunk?

Comment: Think as a label. When error occurs, error output will tell you the name of the chunk.

Comment: You can also repeat a chunk by writing a chunk with no R code, but repeating the name of the original.  It can have different options.